# Event handler raised twice in async method

Tags: c#

I have async method where i am invoking event and it raised two times. I don't know what i am doing wrong. This is my method from where i am invoking:

```
public async Task SyncData(GAT t)
{
    try
    {
        GetInventoryDataResponse response = await GetInventoryData(t);

        List<InventoryData> inventoryData = response.InventoryDataColl;

        //Some logic

        NotifyDataEvent?.Invoke(this, new NotifyEventArgs(Result.Success));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.WarnWithException("Unable to sync", ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

This is my class where i register and un-register the event. In constructor i am registering it:

```
_stationAgent.NotifyDataEvent += NotifyData;
```

In dispose method i unregister this event

```
_stationAgent.NotifyDataEvent -= NotifyData;
```

But notifydata raised multiple times. What's the issue?

Comment: Well, most likely you have registered more than once, or you're calling Invoke more than once.

Comment: No, I am registering only once and un-register it in dispose too. Also it is invoking one time. Also i have debug it. It invoked from one place for one time only.

Comment: I'd say it is highly unlikely there is a bug in MultiCastDelegate, the bug is most likely in your assumptions. You *are* doing something twice, you just have to find out where.

Comment: Well, i have checked it. Nothing is happening twice. May be this is because i am invoking in async method?  Does async method can be a reason behind it?

Comment: Can you show the code where you register/unregister it? Also, you say you do it in Dispose, are you *calling* Dispose?

Comment: The raised event sends message to GUI and it is sending twice. Also i just checked the GetInvocationList().Length; is 2. How this is possible when i register it once?

Comment: It isn't, as I say, you're registering it twice.

Comment: Yes the constructor is calling twice. Thanks. Let me find the root cause why it is calling twice.

Comment: Can you show the constructor(s) that is registering this?

Comment: I got the issue. Event was registering multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check invocation list of the event:

```
EventHandler e = NotifyDataEvent;
var count = e.GetInvocationList().Length;
```

If `count = 2` then you call `NotifyDataEvent +=...` twice. If  `count = 1` then you call `NotifyDataEvent.Invoke...` twice.

Comment: The count is 2 and i don't know why because i am doing NotifyDataEvent += once. Dispose it alsoe.

Comment: @umer Just debug, set breakpoint in the place where `NotifyDataEvent +=..` happens

Comment: It is called twice. Let me see it the root cause.

Comment: Thanks. I got the issue. e.GetInvocationList().Length; helped me.